# Can I run the SSIS Transfer Database Task as member of db_owner role?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions

I'm attempting to transfer a database (online mode) from server A to server B, using a SSIS package running on server C.
The SSIS package access server A with a SQL Server login, which is a member of the db_owner role in the database to be transferred.

When I verify the package I get error `0x80131501`, which is somewhat ambiguous and doesn't help very much.

According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-database-task?view=sql-server-ver15), "*the user who runs the package must be a member of the sysadmin server role or the database owner (dbo) of the selected database*"

Is it enough to be a member of the db_owner role to transfer a database?
I'm not sure about the distinction (permission wise) between the `db_owner` role and the database owner.

Answer (score 0):

Though 8 months later, I encountered the same issue and resolved it.  I was not aware the link in your post, but my experience in this matter is:

1. The account I used has **"sysadmin"** server role.
2. If I granted the account **"db_owner"** role of the database I was going to migrate, it
   failed.  If not, the migration passed.